# Importar Excel a base de datos MySQL usando Visual Basic

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, visual-studio, vb.net, excel

Tengo una consulta, estoy desarrollando una aplicación en visual basic y necesito que dicha aplicación suba archivos de Excel a una base de datos MySQL, es decir la información que se encuentra en ellas se guarden en una tabla, utilizo MySQL Workbench 8.0 ¿De que forma puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Te puede resultar mas simple exportar a csv y usar [`LOAD DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).  O considera usar MySQLProv OLE DB/ODBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, básicamente lo que he hecho es importar los datos del documento de Excel a un datagridview, después inserte el contenido en la tabla de MySQL.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).